# Dynamical critical exponent in stochastic vector model

Tags: field-theory, renormalization, critical-phenomena

For stochastic $O(N)$ model given by:

$$S[\psi,\phi]=\int \frac{d\omega\, dk^D}{(2\pi)^{D+1}} \left( \vec{\psi}(-k,-\omega).\vec{\phi}(k,\omega) \left(-i\omega + \gamma k^2+r \right) -2T\vec{\psi}(-k,-\omega).\vec{\psi}(k,\omega)\right) + \int dt\,dx^D u \, (\vec{\phi}.\vec{\phi})(\vec{\phi}.\vec{\psi}) $$

I want to use Wilsonian RG to find the scaling behavior. The problem is the sunrise diagram given by (omitting extra factors):
$$I(k^2,\omega)=\int_{\Lambda-\delta \Lambda}\frac{dq^d}{(2\pi)^D}\int_{\Lambda-\delta \Lambda}\frac{dq'^d}{(2\pi)^D}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{d\nu}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{d\nu'}{2\pi}\frac{1}{-i\nu+\gamma q^2}\frac{1}{\nu'^2+(\gamma q'^2)^2}\frac{1}{(\nu'-\nu+\omega)^2+\gamma^2(\vec{q}'-\vec{q}+\vec{k})^4}$$
There is another constraint given by:
$$\Lambda-\delta \Lambda < |\vec{q}'-\vec{q}+\vec{k}|<\Lambda$$
We can evaluate frequency integrals and get (again putting away numerical factors):
$$I(k^2,\omega)\propto \int_{\Lambda-\delta \Lambda}\frac{dq^d}{(2\pi)^D}\int_{\Lambda-\delta \Lambda}\frac{dq'^d}{(2\pi)^D} \frac{1}{q'^2|\vec{q}'-\vec{q}+\vec{k}|^2}\frac{1}{-i\omega+\gamma(q^2+q'^2+|\vec{q}'-\vec{q}+\vec{k}|^2)}$$

To me, it seems that the available phase space for integrals scales with $\delta \Lambda^3$ for $k\to 0$ and therefore
$$\frac{\partial I}{\partial \omega}\bigg|_{k=0,\omega=0}\sim \delta \Lambda^3 \to 0$$

while for small but non zero $k$ the phase space is proportional to $\delta \Lambda k^2$ and we will get a finite contribution for the Laplacian term in the effective action. While my calculation for the $k^2$ term agrees with the one in the literature, there seems to be a non-zero contribution to the $-i\omega$ term, too.

I am aware of the calculation using dimensional regularization where:
$$\Gamma^{(2)}_{\psi \phi}(k=0,\omega)\propto -i\omega (1+c_1 \ln 
\omega)$$

But I cannot obtain a consistent result in the Wilson approach.

One possibility is that since we are only coarse graining in the momentum space, the resulting IR action contains all frequencies and therefore, I have to do perturbative RG and find the 2PI 2-point function for the Wilson-Fisher fixed point. This would mean that, if we also coarse grain in the frequency space, we should get the desired result (probably the same phase space argument can be applied here too?)

Comment: Not sure which source you are following, but section 7.1.3 in these notes by Tauber may be useful: http://www1.phys.vt.edu/~tauber/ch_7.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the link. I am following the original papers by Halperin and others, and they do RG in a mixed way, a part is done via Wilson mode decimation and part is done using field theory RG. I know that a big issue is the difference between the order of time and space derivatives in the action (the zeroth order dynamical exponent is not equal to 1) so one cannot consider narrow spherical shells in both momentum and frequency spaces.